# Android media provider does not get recently added images

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, media

I want to fetch all the images in android device. Therefore I used this code to fetch images-

```
private fun getAllShownImagesPath(activity: Activity): ArrayList<String>
{
    val uri: Uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val listOfAllImages = ArrayList<String>()
    var absolutePathOfImage : String

    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
    val orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED
    val cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy)
    val indexData = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)

    cursor.moveToLast()
    while (cursor.moveToPrevious())
    {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(indexData)
        listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage)
    }
    cursor.close()

    return listOfAllImages
}
```

But this does not returns recently added images like if you downloaded it few hours ago.
This is somehow fixed when you reboot the device or the image you want to access is like one day old. 
Note- you can also provide solution in java.

Thanks

Comment: see `android.media.MediaScannerConnection
`

Comment: @pskink I am talking about images added by other applications like camera or browser etc.

Answer (score 0):

Forcefully send broadcast then media cursor will be updated. call this before access media cursor

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: I am talking about images added by other applications like camera or downloaded by browser